# ClassNotFound error even after adding the MySql Connector jar file to my project's Libraries folder in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Most solutions keep saying to add the connector jar file. But even after doing so in the libraries folder, I keep getting the ClassNotFoundException. The code is given below.

```java
package javaapplication2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        public NewJFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            String name = jTextField1.getText();
            String email = jTextField2.getText();
            String Gender = " ";
            String Android = " ";
            if (jRadioButton1.isSelected())
                Gender = "Male";
            else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected())
                Gender = "Female";
            String lang = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (jCheckBox1.isSelected())
                Android = "With Android";
            else if (jCheckBox2.isSelected())
                Android = "Without Android";

            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Successfully Registered");
            try {
                Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library", "root", "");
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?))");
                ps.setString(1, name);
                ps.setString(2, Gender);
                ps.setString(3, email);
                ps.setString(4, lang);
                ps.setString(5, Android);
                ps.executeUpdate();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

In the above two images you can see that I've added the connector file and also created the connection in services, but I still get the error when I run the file. Please help me solve it. I am a beginner and I've been trying for hours now.

Comment: try com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ?

Comment: in the Class.forName() function?

Comment: yeah, its possible that your connector is using a different driver.

Comment: So i did that and now its showing a different exception. "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException. You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to user near ')' at line 1"

Comment: that should indicate there is something wrong with your prepared statement SQL syntax. I believe the issue with the classNotFoundException should be resolved.

Comment: my suggestion would be to go with the full proper sql syntax ie "insert into user (name, Gender, email, lang, android) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" or whatever the appropriate column names in your db are

Comment: okay. ill try that

Comment: oh, fyi, i just saw that your original syntax had double "))" at the end so that would definitely be wrong. regardless, nothing wrong with using full proper sql syntax

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly. Thankyou so much. You have no idea how much youve helped me rn. Also it would be great if you could just explain in short what difference was created by writing com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver instead of what i was writing,

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is in mysql-connector-java 5,
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver is in mysql-connector-java 6, so if you use something below ur jar's version, it will cause error. something like not being backwards compatible? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html#:~:text=The%20name%20of%20the%20class,mysql.

Comment: You have two right brackets Inthe sql. You should have one.

Comment: @YHStan MySQL Connector/J 8 still contains the old class name for backwards compatibility. The problem here is the OP was using an invalid/non-existent driver name (`com.jdbc.mysql.Driver`)

Comment: ah right. i took a closer look at the link and the jdbc and mysql has swapped positions isnt it?

Comment: @YHStan Yes, that's right